# How to list my custom commands only (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Laravel has `php artisan list` command. It shows all available commands.
I've created a bunch of custom commands in `app/Console/Commands` folder. I see them in a list of all commands. But is there a way to show ONLY my commands in that list? To hide Laravel built-in commands from that list?

Comment: Let's say I've created command `php artisan ip:add`. And then another 10 commands. How to list them? How to list only my commands?

Comment: It is good practice to put your custom commands under a custom namespace. So instead of `ip:add `you should make it `petr:ip:add` for your exact reason above.

Answer (score 4):

If you type

```
php artisan list -help
```

It will output

```
 The list command lists all commands:
  
    artisan list
  
  You can also display the commands for a specific namespace:
  
    artisan list test
```

So if your commands are put under your own namespace, eg. `petr` you can run

```
php artisan list petr
```

To only see commands under that namespace.

Comment: Yes, I know about namespaces. But we have multiple namespaces.

Comment: `php artisan list one-namespace && php artisan list two-namespaces` or `php artisan list | grep <your-grep-here>`

Comment: That's nothing more than a workaround